# How to invoke a private constructor via reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

When I select a private constructor from the class members and try to instantiate an object a `java.lang.NoSuchMethod` exception is thrown.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> class test private( s: String ) {
     | def this( i: Int ) = this( i.toString ) // public
     | }
defined class test

scala> val mirror = runtimeMirror( getClass.getClassLoader )
mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.ns...

scala> val cls = mirror.classSymbol( classOf[test] )
cls: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = class test

scala> cls.toType.members.toSeq
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = Scopes(constructor test, constructor test, value s, meth...

scala> val prv = res0( 1 ).asMethod
prv: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = constructor test

scala> val pub = res0( 0 ).asMethod
pub: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = constructor test

scala> mirror.reflectClass( cls ).reflectConstructor( pub ).apply( 1 )
res3: Any = test@6926e27

scala> mirror.reflectClass( cls ).reflectConstructor( prv ).apply( "1" )
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.<init>(java.lang.String) ...
```

I expected to find methods that allow me to flag the private constructor as accessible but I could not find any.

Comment: Try the java reflection API on that method. Of course you will have to find a way to find the method in the java API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug.

The other member lookups use `getDeclaredXXX`, and it's clear from the before and after of [this commit of `ConstructorMirror`](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/f657c375706773ca7b6d2f4f554e7414b35c67b0#L1L467) that it was always intended to `setAccessible`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this link](https://gist.github.com/Akjir/4616615) as inspiration, I made an example using Java Reflection which may be of use:

```
class test private( s: String ) {
    def this( i: Int ) = this( i.toString ) // public
    override def toString() = "Value: " + s
}

val testClass = classOf[test]
val ctor = testClass.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[String])
ctor.setAccessible(true)
val inst = ctor.newInstance("hello")
println(inst)
```

Output:

```
Value: hello
```